# Google visualization - motion chart

Tags: google-visualization

I'm using Google Visualization motion chart to display different reports. One report shows  executable lines of code vs. warnings in each file. Following is what the chart looks like. The x-axis represents eloc and the y axis represents warnings in each file. When the chart is loaded, as you can see all the files are represented with blue balls except for one file, it's displayed with a red ball. what does that mean? is that a bug? I've tried looking on line to find explanations but no luck.

[image]

Following is my code:

```
public class DashboardWidget 
{
    private HorizontalPanel containerPanel=null;
private DataTable data=null;

public DashboardWidget()
{
    containerPanel = new HorizontalPanel();
}
public HorizontalPanel getContainerPanel()
{
    SQLRunnerAsync service = (SQLRunnerAsync) GWT.create(SQLRunner.class);
    AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>> callback = new AsyncCallback<ArrayList<String[]>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) 
        {
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final ArrayList<String[]> result)
        {
            Runnable onLoadCallback = new Runnable() 
            {
                public void run() 
                {

                    data = DataTable.create();
                    data.addColumn(ColumnType.STRING, "Name");
                    data.addColumn(ColumnType.DATE, "Date");
                    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Option1");
                    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Option2");
                    data.addColumn(ColumnType.NUMBER, "Option3");

                    data.addRows(result.size());

                    Date date = new Date();
                    DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    Date d1 = fmt.parse(fmt.format(date));

                    int i;
                    for(i=0;i<result.size();i++)
                    {
                        String[] temp = result.get(i);
                        String Name=temp[0];//name
                        String Option1 = temp[1];
                        String Option2=temp[2];
                        String Option3=temp[3];

                        data.setValue(i, 0, Name);//NAME
                        data.setValue(i, 1, d1);//date
                        data.setValue(i, 2, Integer.parseInt(Option1));
                        data.setValue(i, 3, Integer.parseInt(Option2));
                        data.setValue(i, 4, Integer.parseInt(Option13));
                    }   


                    Options options = Options.create();
                    options.setWidth(1000);
                    options.setHeight(1000);

                    MotionChart chart = new MotionChart(data, options);
                    containerPanel.add(chart);
                }
            };
            VisualizationUtils.loadVisualizationApi(onLoadCallback, MotionChart.PACKAGE);               
        }
    };
    service.getData("","","","", callback);
    return containerPanel;
}
```

}

Comment: Id guess that it could be data related and maybe trying to show you some difference from the other results. Maybe try generating the chart with one half of the data to see if still shows red. Then try with the other half to narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
data.setValue(i, 4, Integer.parseInt(Option13));
```

be

```
data.setValue(i, 4, Integer.parseInt(Option3));
```